# How to project pixels on eigenvectors in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pca

given a contour, I can extract mean, and eigenvectors by performing PCA. Then I want to project all pixels inside a contour on an eigenvector. Below are my code and my images

my input images [image: my input images]

Read image, extract contours, and draw the first component

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile('/Users/bryan/Desktop/lung.png'))
gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def drawAxis(img, p_, q_, colour, scale):
    p = list(p_)
    q = list(q_)
    ## [visualization1]
    angle = atan2(p[1] - q[1], p[0] - q[0])  # angle in radians
    hypotenuse = sqrt((p[1] - q[1]) * (p[1] - q[1]) + (p[0] - q[0]) * (p[0] - q[0]))

    # Here we lengthen the arrow by a factor of scale
    q[0] = p[0] - scale * hypotenuse * cos(angle)
    q[1] = p[1] - scale * hypotenuse * sin(angle)
    cv.line(img, (int(p[0]), int(p[1])), (int(q[0]), int(q[1])), colour, 1, cv.LINE_AA)

    # create the arrow hooks
    p[0] = q[0] + 9 * cos(angle + pi / 4)
    p[1] = q[1] + 9 * sin(angle + pi / 4)
    cv.line(img, (int(p[0]), int(p[1])), (int(q[0]), int(q[1])), colour, 1, cv.LINE_AA)

    p[0] = q[0] + 9 * cos(angle - pi / 4)
    p[1] = q[1] + 9 * sin(angle - pi / 4)
    cv.line(img, (int(p[0]), int(p[1])), (int(q[0]), int(q[1])), colour, 1, cv.LINE_AA)
    
def getOrientation(pts, img, scale_factor=25):
    ## [pca]
    # Construct a buffer used by the pca analysis
    sz = len(pts)
    data_pts = np.empty((sz, 2), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(data_pts.shape[0]):
        data_pts[i, 0] = pts[i, 0, 0]
        data_pts[i, 1] = pts[i, 0, 1]

    # Perform PCA analysis
    mean = np.empty(0)
    mean, eigenvectors, eigenvalues = cv.PCACompute2(data_pts, mean)

    # Store the center of the object
    cntr = (int(mean[0, 0]), int(mean[0, 1]))
    ## [pca]

    ## [visualization]
    # Draw the principal components
    cv.circle(img, cntr, 3, (255, 0, 255), 2)

    p1 = (
        cntr[0] + scale_factor * eigenvectors[0, 0],
        cntr[1] + scale_factor * eigenvectors[0, 1])
    p2 = (
        cntr[0] - scale_factor * eigenvectors[1, 0],
        cntr[1] - scale_factor * eigenvectors[1, 1])
    drawAxis(img, cntr, p1, (0, 255, 0), 4)
    
    ## [visualization]

    # doing projections along eigenvectors
    dim1_ = []
    for _ in data_pts:
        p = make_vector_projection(_, np.array(p1))
        dim1_.append(p.astype(int))
    dim1 = np.array(dim1_)

    dim2_ = []
    for _ in data_pts:
        p = make_vector_projection(_, np.array(p2))
        dim2_.append(p.astype(int))
    dim2 = np.array(dim2_)

    return mean, eigenvectors, eigenvalues, p1, p2, dim1, dim2

for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    mean, evecs, evalues, p1, p2, dim1, dim2 = getOrientation(c, src)

    
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.axis('equal')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.imshow(src)
```

[image]

Look as I expected but I want to double-check, I compute angles between a random vector in the first dimension and the first eigenvector. I defined

```
def unit_vector(vector):
    """ Returns the unit vector of the vector.  """
    return vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)


def angle_between(v1, v2):
    """ Returns the angle in radians between vectors 'v1' and 'v2'::

            >>> angle_between((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0))
            1.5707963267948966
            >>> angle_between((1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0))
            0.0
            >>> angle_between((1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 0))
            3.141592653589793
    """
    v1_u = unit_vector(v1)
    v2_u = unit_vector(v2)
    return np.arccos(np.clip(np.dot(v1_u, v2_u), -1.0, 1.0))



for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    mean, evecs, evalues, p1, p2, dim1, dim2 = getOrientation(c, src)
    draw_point = dim1[45].astype(int)  # extract the first dimension
    print(draw_point, evecs[0], angle_between(draw_point, p1))
    print('#'* 10)
```

I got output like below, angle_between is in radian, close to zero means they are paralleled

```
[ 97 148] [ 0.14189901 -0.98988114] 0.002321780300502494
##########
[332 163] [-0.22199134 -0.97504864] 0.0006249775357550807
##########
```

My problem occurs when I want to plot projected points on eigenvectors. Points I plotted don't lie on green line (my eigenvector). My code is

```
point_colors = [
    (0, 0, 255), # blue
    (0, 255, 0) # green
]

for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    mean, evecs, evalues, p1, p2, dim1, dim2 = getOrientation(c, src)
    draw_point = dim1[45].astype(int)
    print(draw_point, evecs[0], angle_between(draw_point, p1))
    cv.circle(src, (draw_point[1], draw_point[0]), 7, point_colors[i], 2) # plot point
    print('#'* 10)
```

and output [image: output]

My question is, I want to plot all projected pixels on the eigenvector lines, but my calculation doesn't seem correct as points don't lie on the eigenvector lines. Could you help?

Comment: Why do we need eigenvectors? just for my knowledge

Comment: hi @coder_v_3.0, I want to measure width, height of an object. they are difined as largest parts of an object

Comment: why don't you go with contours's minimum x, minimum y maximum x maximum y if yo need to know the height and width

Comment: because the largest parts don't usually parallel to the x-axis or y-axis. In fact, I think I can use `cv.minAreaRect`